# Semi Supervised learning for tabular data VIME for 1-dimensional y_test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, semisupervised-learning

The vime_semi.py file of the Tensorflow implementation of VIME (https://github.com/jsyoon0823/VIME) has been implemented, assuming that y_train, y_test will be a 2-d array. In my dataset I have a 1-d array for y_train and y_test. So far, I have done the following, but I am getting some error.

#original

```
"""VIME: Extending the Success of Self- and Semi-supervised Learning to Tabular Domain (VIME) Codebase.

Reference: Jinsung Yoon, Yao Zhang, James Jordon, Mihaela van der Schaar, 
"VIME: Extending the Success of Self- and Semi-supervised Learning to Tabular Domain," 
Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS), 2020.
Paper link: TBD
Last updated Date: October 11th 2020
Code author: Jinsung Yoon (jsyoon0823@gmail.com)
-----------------------------

vime_semi.py
- Semi-supervised learning parts of the VIME framework
- Using both labeled and unlabeled data to train the predictor with the help of trained encoder
"""

# Necessary packages
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers as contrib_layers

from vime_utils import mask_generator, pretext_generator


def vime_semi(x_train, y_train, x_unlab, x_test, parameters,
              p_m, K, beta, file_name):
    """Semi-supervied learning part in VIME.

    Args:
      - x_train, y_train: training dataset
      - x_unlab: unlabeled dataset
      - x_test: testing features
      - parameters: network parameters (hidden_dim, batch_size, iterations)
      - p_m: corruption probability
      - K: number of augmented samples
      - beta: hyperparameter to control supervised and unsupervised loss
      - file_name: saved filed name for the encoder function

    Returns:
      - y_test_hat: prediction on x_test
    """

    # Network parameters
    hidden_dim = parameters['hidden_dim']
    act_fn = tf.nn.relu
    batch_size = parameters['batch_size']
    iterations = parameters['iterations']

    # Basic parameters
    data_dim = len(x_train[0, :])
    label_dim = len(y_train[0, :])

    # Divide training and validation sets (9:1)
    idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train[:, 0]))
    train_idx = idx[:int(len(idx)*0.9)]
    valid_idx = idx[int(len(idx)*0.9):]

    x_valid = x_train[valid_idx, :]
    y_valid = y_train[valid_idx, :]

    x_train = x_train[train_idx, :]
    y_train = y_train[train_idx, :]

    # Input placeholder
    # Labeled data
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

    x_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, data_dim])
    y_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, label_dim])

    # Augmented unlabeled data
    xu_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, data_dim])

    # Predictor
    def predictor(x_input):
        """Returns prediction.

        Args: 
          - x_input: input feature

        Returns:
          - y_hat_logit: logit prediction
          - y_hat: prediction
        """
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('predictor', reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
            # Stacks multi-layered perceptron
            inter_layer = contrib_layers.Dense(
                hidden_dim, activation=act_fn)(x_input)
            inter_layer = contrib_layers.Dense(
                hidden_dim, activation=act_fn)(inter_layer)
            y_hat_logit = contrib_layers.Dense(
                label_dim, activation=None)(inter_layer)
            y_hat = tf.nn.softmax(y_hat_logit)

            return y_hat_logit, y_hat

    # Build model
    y_hat_logit, y_hat = predictor(x_input)
    yv_hat_logit, yv_hat = predictor(xu_input)

    # Defin losses
    # Supervised loss
    y_loss = tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y_input, y_hat_logit)
    # Unsupervised loss
    yu_loss = tf.compat.v1.reduce_mean(tf.nn.moments(yv_hat_logit, axes=0)[1])

    # Define variables
    p_vars = [v for v in tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
              if v.name.startswith('predictor')]
    # Define solver
    solver = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(y_loss +
                                                         beta * yu_loss, var_list=p_vars)

    # Load encoder from self-supervised model
    encoder = keras.models.load_model(file_name)

    # Encode validation and testing features
    x_valid = encoder.predict(x_valid)
    x_test = encoder.predict(x_test)

    # Start session
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    # Setup early stopping procedure
    class_file_name = './save_model/class_model.ckpt'
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(p_vars)

    yv_loss_min = 1e10
    yv_loss_min_idx = -1

    # Training iteration loop
    for it in range(iterations):

        # Select a batch of labeled data
        batch_idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train[:, 0]))[:batch_size]
        x_batch = x_train[batch_idx, :]
        y_batch = y_train[batch_idx, :]

        # Encode labeled data
        x_batch = encoder.predict(x_batch)

        # Select a batch of unlabeled data
        batch_u_idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_unlab[:, 0]))[:batch_size]
        xu_batch_ori = x_unlab[batch_u_idx, :]

        # Augment unlabeled data
        xu_batch = list()

        for rep in range(K):
            # Mask vector generation
            m_batch = mask_generator(p_m, xu_batch_ori)
            # Pretext generator
            _, xu_batch_temp = pretext_generator(m_batch, xu_batch_ori)

            # Encode corrupted samples
            xu_batch_temp = encoder.predict(xu_batch_temp)
            xu_batch = xu_batch + [xu_batch_temp]
        # Convert list to matrix
        xu_batch = np.asarray(xu_batch)

        # Train the model
        _, y_loss_curr = sess.run([solver, y_loss],
                                  feed_dict={x_input: x_batch, y_input: y_batch,
                                             xu_input: xu_batch})
        # Current validation loss
        yv_loss_curr = sess.run(y_loss, feed_dict={x_input: x_valid,
                                                   y_input: y_valid})

        if it % 100 == 0:
            print('Iteration: ' + str(it) + '/' + str(iterations) +
                  ', Current loss: ' + str(np.round(yv_loss_curr, 4)))

        # Early stopping & Best model save
        if yv_loss_min > yv_loss_curr:
            yv_loss_min = yv_loss_curr
            yv_loss_min_idx = it

            # Saves trained model
            saver.save(sess, class_file_name)

        if yv_loss_min_idx + 100 < it:
            break

    # %% Restores the saved model
    imported_graph = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(
        class_file_name + '.meta')

    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    imported_graph.restore(sess, class_file_name)

    # Predict on x_test
    y_test_hat = sess.run(y_hat, feed_dict={x_input: x_test})

    return y_test_hat
```

## My code

```
"""VIME: Extending the Success of Self- and Semi-supervised Learning to Tabular Domain (VIME) Codebase.

Reference: Jinsung Yoon, Yao Zhang, James Jordon, Mihaela van der Schaar, 
"VIME: Extending the Success of Self- and Semi-supervised Learning to Tabular Domain," 
Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS), 2020.
Paper link: TBD
Last updated Date: October 11th 2020
Code author: Jinsung Yoon (jsyoon0823@gmail.com)
-----------------------------

vime_semi.py
- Semi-supervised learning parts of the VIME framework
- Using both labeled and unlabeled data to train the predictor with the help of trained encoder
"""

# Necessary packages
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers as contrib_layers

from vime_utils import mask_generator, pretext_generator


def vime_semi(x_train, y_train, x_unlab, x_test, parameters,
              p_m, K, beta, file_name):
    """Semi-supervied learning part in VIME.

    Args:
      - x_train, y_train: training dataset
      - x_unlab: unlabeled dataset
      - x_test: testing features
      - parameters: network parameters (hidden_dim, batch_size, iterations)
      - p_m: corruption probability
      - K: number of augmented samples
      - beta: hyperparameter to control supervised and unsupervised loss
      - file_name: saved filed name for the encoder function

    Returns:
      - y_test_hat: prediction on x_test
    """

    # Network parameters
    hidden_dim = parameters['hidden_dim']
    act_fn = tf.nn.relu
    batch_size = parameters['batch_size']
    iterations = parameters['iterations']

    # Basic parameters
    data_dim = len(x_train[0, :])
    label_dim = len(y_train)

    print("LABEL DIM: ", label_dim)

    # Divide training and validation sets (9:1)
    idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train[:, 0]))
    train_idx = idx[:int(len(idx)*0.9)]
    valid_idx = idx[int(len(idx)*0.9):]

    x_valid = x_train[valid_idx, :]
    y_valid = y_train[valid_idx]

    x_train = x_train[train_idx, :]
    y_train = y_train[train_idx]

    # Input placeholder
    # Labeled data
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

    x_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, data_dim])
    y_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, label_dim])

    # Augmented unlabeled data
    xu_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, data_dim])

    # Predictor
    def predictor(x_input):
        """Returns prediction.

        Args: 
          - x_input: input feature

        Returns:
          - y_hat_logit: logit prediction
          - y_hat: prediction
        """
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('predictor', reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
            # Stacks multi-layered perceptron
            inter_layer = contrib_layers.Dense(
                hidden_dim, activation=act_fn)(x_input)
            inter_layer = contrib_layers.Dense(
                hidden_dim, activation=act_fn)(inter_layer)
            y_hat_logit = contrib_layers.Dense(
                label_dim, activation=None)(inter_layer)
            y_hat = tf.nn.softmax(y_hat_logit)

            return y_hat_logit, y_hat

    # Build model
    y_hat_logit, y_hat = predictor(x_input)
    yv_hat_logit, yv_hat = predictor(xu_input)

    # Defin losses
    # Supervised loss
    y_loss = tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y_input, y_hat_logit)
    # Unsupervised loss
    yu_loss = tf.compat.v1.reduce_mean(tf.nn.moments(yv_hat_logit, axes=0)[1])

    # Define variables
    p_vars = [v for v in tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
              if v.name.startswith('predictor')]
    # Define solver
    solver = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(y_loss +
                                                         beta * yu_loss, var_list=p_vars)

    # Load encoder from self-supervised model
    encoder = keras.models.load_model(file_name)

    # Encode validation and testing features
    x_valid = encoder.predict(x_valid)
    x_test = encoder.predict(x_test)

    # Start session
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    # Setup early stopping procedure
    class_file_name = './save_model/class_model.ckpt'
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(p_vars)

    yv_loss_min = 1e10
    yv_loss_min_idx = -1

    # Training iteration loop
    for it in range(iterations):

        # Select a batch of labeled data
        batch_idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train[:, 0]))[:batch_size]
        x_batch = x_train[batch_idx, :]
        y_batch = y_train[batch_idx]

        # Encode labeled data
        x_batch = encoder.predict(x_batch)

        # Select a batch of unlabeled data
        batch_u_idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_unlab[:, 0]))[:batch_size]
        xu_batch_ori = x_unlab[batch_u_idx, :]

        # Augment unlabeled data
        xu_batch = list()

        for rep in range(K):
            # Mask vector generation
            m_batch = mask_generator(p_m, xu_batch_ori)
            # Pretext generator
            _, xu_batch_temp = pretext_generator(m_batch, xu_batch_ori)

            # Encode corrupted samples
            xu_batch_temp = encoder.predict(xu_batch_temp)
            xu_batch = xu_batch + [xu_batch_temp]
        # Convert list to matrix
        xu_batch = np.asarray(xu_batch)

        # Train the model
        _, y_loss_curr = sess.run([solver, y_loss],
                                  feed_dict={x_input: x_batch, y_input: y_batch,
                                             xu_input: xu_batch})
        # Current validation loss
        yv_loss_curr = sess.run(y_loss, feed_dict={x_input: x_valid,
                                                   y_input: y_valid})

        if it % 100 == 0:
            print('Iteration: ' + str(it) + '/' + str(iterations) +
                  ', Current loss: ' + str(np.round(yv_loss_curr, 4)))

        # Early stopping & Best model save
        if yv_loss_min > yv_loss_curr:
            yv_loss_min = yv_loss_curr
            yv_loss_min_idx = it

            # Saves trained model
            saver.save(sess, class_file_name)

        if yv_loss_min_idx + 100 < it:
            break

    # %% Restores the saved model
    imported_graph = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(
        class_file_name + '.meta')

    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    imported_graph.restore(sess, class_file_name)

    # Predict on x_test
    y_test_hat = sess.run(y_hat, feed_dict={x_input: x_test})

    return y_test_hat
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor Placeholder_1:0, which has shape (None, 1000)

in  _, y_loss_curr = sess.run([solver, y_loss],
```